# Modular Simultaneous Equations

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Can someone please help me out, as normally i am only use to dealing with one unknown for modular simultaneous equations.

The question is, solve :

$x + 2y \equiv 3 \mod 7$

$3x+ y \equiv 2 \mod 7$

Any answer/explanation would be much appreciated

Comment: Solve the first for $\,x,\,$ then substitute for $\,x\,$ in the second, then solve for $\,y.\ $ Or use Cramer's rule, or row-reduction, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Work in the field $\mathbf Z/7\mathbf Z$ and use Gauß's pivot method: the system is equivalent to 
\begin{alignat*}{2}\bar x+2\bar y=3\\-5\bar y=0\end{alignat*}
whence $\bar y=0, \bar x=\bar 3$, or in terms of congruences:
$$x\equiv 3,\enspace y\equiv 0\pmod 7.$$